# socket programming in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sockets

i have two machines running MATLAB and i need to exchange information(numbers,images) between them,is there a way in MATLAB i can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) and [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/), you can use MPI-style programming to send data between the two MATLAB processes. You can use functions like `labSend` and `labReceive` to send and receive data.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities without any extra toolboxes, depending on your specific needs. Check the Matlab help about [external interfaces](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bp_kqh7.html) for details. For high performance, mexing a custom C communication is probably your best option. Using shared files on a network storage would be an alternative that is easier to implement but less effective, especially if you need frequent communication.

Answer (score 0):

for an example of socket programming in MATLAB using Java, see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675611/writing-java-code-in-matlab/2677627#2677627)

Answer (score 0):

Adding some specifics to other answers, [here's an example of using Java for sockets](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab).  [multicore](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13775) and [MatlabMPI](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/isr/matlabmpi/matlabmpi.html) use the filesystem, so I believe if you have a shared network filesystem you could use them across machines.  And [here is an old implementation in C++](http://code.google.com/p/msocket/).

We have direct experience only with `multicore`, which is the least like real socket communication out of the above, but it gets the job done for coarsely parallel jobs.