# socket programing can be done in matlab

Tags: matlab

can we do a socket programing in MATLAb, ans also what to known the codes for using list box in GUI, when we made a code for transfer of data or a value from list box to edit box due to pressing of push button

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do.

you can use MPI-style programming to send data between the two MATLAB processes.You can use functions like

```
  labSend and labReceive
```

to send and receive data.

also check this becz you required this [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.in/products/parallel-computing/)  and [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.in/products/distriben/)

more details go to  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164348/socket-programming-in-matlab)