# MATLAB Mex Socket Wrapper Library

Tags: linux, sockets, matlab, wrapper, mex

Have anybody written a POSIX socket wrapping library for MATLAB using Mex?

I basically want to open, write and read. Both sync and asynchronous alternatives would be nice. My main target platform is Linux. I know Mex and I know POSIX sockets. I just want to make certain that nobody else has done this already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with sockets, you have two options:

1) use Java capabilities from inside MATLAB (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675611/writing-java-code-in-matlab/2677627#2677627) here on SO for a quick example):

- [TCP/IP Socket Communications in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab)
- [TCP/IP Socket Communications in MATLAB using Java Classes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25249-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab-using-java-classes)

2) use C MEX-wrappers:

- [msocket](http://code.google.com/p/msocket/)
- [TCP/UDP/IP Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345)

I also think that the *Instrument Control Toolbox* includes support for [TCP](http://www.mathworks.com/tcpip) [UDP](http://www.mathworks.com/udp) communication.

Comment: For Windows, a third option is to call into Microsoft .NET libraries from MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb5k6.html (I doubt this will work with Mono on Linux)